# How to make the code more simple, if i need to click a eq(0) show b eq(0) hide others, a eq(1) show b eq(1) hide others..?

Tags: jquery

How to make below code more simple and less?

Thanks.

```
<div class="btn"><div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
<div class="content"><div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>

$('.btn div:eq(0)').click(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $('.content div:eq(0)').show();
});
$('.btn div:eq(1)').click(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $('.content div:eq(1)').show();
});
$('.btn div:eq(2)').click(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $('.content div:eq(2)').show();
});
$('.btn div:eq(3)').click(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $('.content div:eq(3)').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".btn div").click(function () {
   $(".content div").hide().eq($(".btn div").index(this)).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xepmg/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.btn div').click(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $('.content div:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9hS9/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var numClicked = '';

$('.btn div').on('click', function() {
     numClicked = $('.btn div').index(this);
     $('.content div').hide();
     $('.content div').eq(numClicked).show();
});
```

There is an even better way though I can't totally remember how its done.

Comment: @user1775888 this is more or less identical to my answer, but it is less efficient because there are more calls to `$()`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Pills yea obviously you would want to cache the variable that way you are only jumping into the dom once rather than the three times. Theres an even better and easier way I just don't remember it